# как сделать кнопки поверх img?

Tags: css, xhtml

например, в данном случае кнопки Редактировать и Удалить. здесь они просто внизу, а надо именно поверх
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

наверно, можно разместить их внутри img, но это кажется не совсем правильным

Comment: Можно так же (учитывая ответ) использовать отрицательный margin-top и положительный z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поверх img не стоит. Заверни img в div, поставь ему position: relative. В нем еще один div, ему поставь position:absolute. Классика.

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать div с "background-image:url(путь к вашему изображению)", а уже поверх div разместить кнопки